# setState inside setInterval not working as expected. Any Idea why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval, setstate

I want to update the state after every 2 seconds and render some image
**This works absolutely fine**

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (workImages.currentIndex > workImages.items.length - 2) {
        setWorkImages({ ...workImages, currentIndex: 0 });
      } else {
        setWorkImages({
          ...workImages,
          currentIndex: ++workImages.currentIndex,
        });
      }
    }, 2000);
  }, [workImages]);
```

**This works ONLY for else case**

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (workImages.currentIndex > workImages.items.length - 2) {
        setWorkImages({ ...workImages, currentIndex: 0 });
      } else {
        setWorkImages({
          ...workImages,
          currentIndex: ++workImages.currentIndex,
        });
      }
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
```

can anyone explain why?

Comment: Yes because setInterval executes function after every given amount of time (in this case 2 sec or 2000 mils). But setTimeout will execute the function once after given amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `workImages.currentIndex` starts at 1.

In the first example, the first time the function gets called, the `useEffect` gets set up and 2 seconds later the `setTimeout` fires. This updates the state to `workImages.currentIndex` is now 2 which triggers a rerender. Now `workImages` has changed and, since it is a dependency of the `useEffect`, the function gets called again and two seconds later another timeout runs.

Now in the second example, the first time function gets called something very similar happens, but the second time it gets called the `useEffect` doesn't run again. There's no dependency on `workImages`.

Now, you might this that doesn't matter because you are using `setInterval` and not `setTimeout` and you'd be almost right.

2 seconds later, the interval triggers and the function you pass to it runs again.

**However** it has **closed over** the `workImages` variable from the **first** time the function ran, not the second time. The value of `workImages.currentIndex` is (as far as that function is concerned) still 1 because it hasn't got the updated value from the state. So it sets it to 2 again. This isn't a change (it was already 2 so you don't get a rerender. 2 seconds later it sets it to 2 again, and does so for all time.

Answer (score 1):

**First example** works because it listens to workImages. So everytime workImages changes, you set a new image with setWorkImages.

**Second example** only fires *ONCE*, when the page is loaded.

For more information about useEffect, look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

The first one works because you've included the `workImages` array in your **dependency array**: the hook will fire whenever `workImages` changes.

Your second example has an empty dependency array, which means it will fire once when the component mounts, but won't re-fire as `workImages.currentIndex` changes.